# iOS 6 Facebook 'The operation couldn’t be completed.'

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am using Facebook API in my app. On iOS 6, I get this error when logging in via fb:

```
'The operation couldn’t be completed.'
```

Upon researching, apparently, I need to set my bundle id in Facebook app settings page. But I can't find the field anywhere on that page. Can someone tell me exactly where it is/what is it called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select Native iOS App section, where you can find Bundle ID